# Programmatically set color in flutter_material_color_picker inside AlertDialog

Tags: flutter

Inside `AlertDialog` I have `TypeAheadFormField` (from flutter_typeahead) and `MaterialColorPicker`:

```
MaterialColorPicker(
    onMainColorChange: (ColorSwatch color) {
        this._myColor = color;
    },
    selectedColor: _myColor,
)
...
onSuggestionSelected: (validColorInt) {
    this._textController.text = 'THE TEXT IS UPDATED';

    setState(() {
        this._myColor = Color(validColorInt); // BUT NOT THE PICKER
    });
}
```

I want to change the picker's selected color when the user makes a selection. What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you aren't sharing all of the code that is involved here.
With what you shared, to get the color change to reflect on your variable, and based on the documentation of the MaterialColorPicker, your code should look like this:

```
MaterialColorPicker(
  onColorChange: (Color color) {
    setState(() {
      this._myColor = color;
    });
  },
  selectedColor: Colors.red
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can't use setState in a dialog, because a normal dialog does not update state, you have to use an custom dialog